# How does disk I/O work with sectors in C?

Tags: c, linux, io, disk

I'm having trouble understanding disk sectors in Linux and the C language. Take the following code as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("myfile", "rb+");
    char foo;
    fread(&foo, sizeof(foo), 1, fp);
}
```

In this example, if my disk sector size was 512 bytes, would I read 512 bytes from the disk when I call `fread()`? Is it the same for `fwrite()`?

Would best practice be to read an entire sector into memory, make any modifications, and then write the entire sector back to disk?

Comment: Forget sectors, just read and write what you need. There are very few programs that need to be concerned with sectors. The only times I've been concerned with one, I was writing an operating system kernel, a simulation of operating system, and a filesystem driver.

Comment: This too: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/21350/does-fread-really-read-from-the-disc-the-size-and-the-number-of-times-as-it-is